# Tune MapKit searchResults

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm working on an app in which I'm utilizing `MapKit` to be able to search for locations, I got this up and running, however, it's not the desired results that I get back. When I search for e.g. `Eindhoven`, these are my results:

[image]

But when I use Apple Maps to search for Eindhoven, these are the results:

[image]

So I was wondering if there's a way to "tune" the results, so that I can get something more like what maps returns. This is how the search is conducted at the moment:

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.start { response, _ in
    guard let response = response else {
        return
    }

    self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
    self.tableNode.reloadData()
}
```

So how do I make sure I get better search results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apple Maps doesn’t use MKLocalSearchRequest(). So we can’t obtain the same result. You need to use third party API e.g. foursquare, yelp.